# How to config a RateController waiter in Hyperledger Caliper?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

I would like to send transactions with time intervals, for example I want to send 500 transactions but send one by one with a 30 seconds interval period.
How can I do this using RateControllers in Hyperledger Caliper?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `1TX/30s` send rate, which corresponds to `1/30 TPS = 0.033333 TPS`. Just set this value for the [fixed-rate](https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/vLatest/rate-controllers/#fixed-rate) controller's `tps` property.